# Invalid argument type when trying to download specific files from S3 bucket to EC2 using subprocess

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download certain files from S3 to local machine by running the following code:

```
import subprocess, os
ec2_root = '/home/'
s3_root_path = "S3://bucket-name/"
s3_download_command = ["aws", "s3", "cp", os.path.join(s3_root_path, 'my_video.mp4'), os.path.join(local_root)]
p = subprocess.Popen(s3_download_command)
p.communicate()
```

But I get the following error:
`usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri> Error: Invalid argument type`

Comment: please add the values of `s3_root_path` and `local_root` to the question title

Comment: What are the values of `s3_root_path` and `local_root`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I used `S3://` with a capital `S` instead of small `s`.